# Blender Bake Transparency

Tags: transparency

I have some problems in blender to bake transparency. It works fine in 2.79 but its not really working in 2.93, i think i got it to work before but then i forgot how i did it. I have tried all settings i can find that has something to do with transparency but it just wont work.

Here is a youtube video that shows my problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTyKy0mdeao

Comment: Have you tried to search ... there is a lot of links ... [like here](https://www.blendernation.com/2020/05/26/blender-quick-tutorial-how-to-bake-alpha-channels/) ... there is not a direct way. Only plug alpha directly to output and bake separately as black@white image.

Comment: I figured out how i did it before. I used Texture Paint with Clone Brush to paint from the the first texture on to a new texture. But i have always wondered if it was possible in the later versions of Blender. But thanks for letting me know that is no longer possible to do it by baking the texture. The reason i cannot use a separate texture as an alpha texture is because the model will be used for World of Warcraft and it is not possible to use Alpha Maps there. It needs real transparency in same image as diffuse texture.

Comment: sure :) ... btw you can use compositor to merge baked color with baked alpha into final texture (or image sequence).

Comment: Oh that sounds interesting. I have never really used the compositor. It makes me confused. It took my long time enough to learn how the normal Material Nodes work LoL